# How to Get Json Respond Value From Laravel

Tags: laravel

this is my Laravel respond array How i add Addons value in my Database.
i'm using Laravel 5.8

```
    array (
      'User' => 'asasadsd',
      'User_Email' => 'asas@gmail.com',
      'Addons' => '[
        {
            "id": 48,
            "addon_id": "57",
            "user_id": "501855393",
            "booking_id": "477310302",
        },
        {
            "id": 49,
            "addon_id": "59",
            "user_id": "501855393",
            "booking_id": "477310302",
        }
    ]',
    )
```

Comment: Can you give some more insight? Is this a response from the backend, or a `POST` request from the front end?

Comment: Yes This is Back end Using Guzzle Post Request @BrianLogan

Comment: `'form_params' => [
                    'token' => $this->jWTAuthHelper->JWTAuth(),
                    'User' => $data->firstName,
                    'User_Email' => $data->Email,
                    'Addons' => $addons->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),
                    ],
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept'     => 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                ]`

Comment: Okay, for clarification, this is a response from a Guzzle request that you are getting, and you want to save it to a model in Laravel? I guess more code would be helpful but maybe not needed, just don't want to give you a wrong answer.

Comment: This Guzzle Post Request server to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it

```
$store_DB = json_decode($data->Addons, true);
foreach($db as $item) {
    $uses = $item['id'];
}
```